# How to create a custom variant in tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I make `dark` variant following tailwindcss docs, but that doesn't work and in this doc unfortunately, no exact explanation has been given!!

How can I make a variant like this:

```html
<p class="dark:text-white text-gray-700"></p>
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now whenever dark mode is enabled on the user’s operating system, dark:{class} classes will take precedence over unprefixed classes.

The dark mode is only available if your operating system enables it.

Also, maybe you didn't add the dark settings in your tailwind.config.js

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'media',
  // ...
}
```

If you want to support toggling dark mode manually instead of relying on the operating system preference change the media setting for class

Answer (score -4):

```
<p style="color='color'" ></p>
```

write color name of 'color'